# if file_exists in PHP issue wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to create code that checks if an image exists on my site and if not shows a default image. In one case I know the file exists and can get it to link to the file using the variable that I want file_exist to use!

```
$menuCategories = get_categories( array(
   'child_of' => $whichGrade,));

foreach ( $menuCategories as $menuCategory ) { ?>
   <?php
        $linktoicon = get_bloginfo('template_directory') ."/images/menuicon_".$menuCategory->slug.".png";
        if (file_exists($linktoicon)) {
           $iconref = $menuCategory->slug; 
        }else { 
            $iconref = "default";
        } ?>
           <a href='<?php echo $linktoicon;  ?>'> <?phpvar_dump($iconref); ?></a>
<?php }?>
```

$linktoicon` is "http://mybritishhelper.com/wp-content/themes/wpex-magtastico/images/menuicon_colours.png"

Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

PHP's `file_exists` isn't used with URL's, it's used for paths to files on the server itself. Not a problem. First, we need to get the path to your theme's template directory:

```
$templateDirectory = get_template_directory();
```

Assuming that the link you provided is on your own server, the full path to your image is

```
$pathToImage = $templateDirectory . '/images/menuicon_colours.png';
```

We can now check if your image exists with the following

```
if (file_exists($pathToImage)) {
// Do stuff
}
```

Hope this helps. For reference, see the docs for [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and [get_template_directory()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory)